# Clicking on element not hit angularjs directive link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It seems my li elements in angularjs directive not responding clicking event.

HTML:

```
<my-selbg>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="bgimage in bgimages"><img src={{bgimage}} width="85" height="82" dir={{bgimage}}></li>
                            </ul>
                        </my-selbg>
```

JS:

```
var mlwcApp = angular.module('mlwcApp', [])
.controller('BgImagesListController', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/webcontent/bg_images").success(function(response) {
        $scope.bgimages = response;
    });
})
.directive('myselbg', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var elementOne = angular.element(element.children[1]);
            var elementTwo = angular.element(element.children[2]);
            var elementThree = angular.element(element.children[3]);

            setUpBGImg = function(){
                console.log('link function');
            };
            $(elementOne).on('click', setUpBGImg);
            $(elementTwo).on('click', setUpBGImg);
            $(elementThree).on('click', setUpBGImg);
        }
    };
});
```

I have 3 li elements and clicking any of them dose not hit the code in link function. Anyone has idea?

Comment: `children` is a method, shouldn't you do `element.children()[1]`?

Comment: @jjimenez I corrected it, but still not working.

Comment: `elementOne` is already a jqlite element, try to do `elementOne.on(...)` directly (without `$(`). Maybe you could provide a plunkr or something.

Comment: @jjimenez strip off $ still not working, I could not put my code onto plunkr since the backend service is on my local PC and my internet provider banned to expose all ports. I have not moved my code to public server yet...

Comment: @user3500605: Fiddled it for you, and actually made it work. Check the answers.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're new to angular, by the looks of it.

First off, before going any further - your directive will not even bind at all in the state it is in. You've got an element directive (which is fine, though if I were you I'd make it an attribute directive by restricting on `A`, which allows you to then apply it to the list rather than an element above it) named `myselbg` in your code. However, your markup is set as `my-selbg`, which would then look for the angular directive `mySelbg`, which does not exist.

In addition to this, your directive will evaluate **before** the list is rendered (thanks to the order of priority in execution). You have two choices to go around this:

- You can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/a01n3srw/1/ . Really not recommended - I am using `$timeout` in order to evaluate code after the current refresh cycle is done, at which point the list fully exists
- You can use the simple `ngClick` angular core directive in order to make this easy. Added bonus, when your function that you evaluate starts modifying scope, you won't shoot yourself in the foot using the previous method and having to use `$apply`

Comment: That's cool and thanks. I am new to Angularjs and the official guide it not so easy to understand :(